# bert-for-tf2 : albert classification error(Failed copying input tensor from GPU in order to run Identity: GPU sync failed [Op:Identity])

Tags: tensorflow, synchronization, gpu

```
#tokenization 정의 - vocab를 이용하여
from bert.tokenization.albert_tokenization import FullTokenizer
def createTokenizer():
    return FullTokenizer("../albert_base/assets/30k-clean.vocab", spm_model_file="../albert_base/assets/30k-clean.model", do_lower_case=True)
def get_masks(tokens, max_seq_length):
"""Mask for padding"""
    if len(tokens)>max_seq_length:
        #Cutting down the excess length
        tokens = tokens[0:max_seq_length]
        return [1]*len(tokens)
    else :
          return [1]*len(tokens) + [0] * (max_seq_length - len(tokens))

def get_segments(tokens, max_seq_length):
    if len(tokens)>max_seq_length:
      #Cutting down the excess length
      tokens = tokens[:max_seq_length]
      segments = []
      current_segment_id = 0
      for token in tokens:
        segments.append(current_segment_id)
        if token == "[SEP]":
          current_segment_id = 1
      return segments
    else:
      segments = []
      current_segment_id = 0
      for token in tokens:
        segments.append(current_segment_id)
        if token == "[SEP]":
          current_segment_id = 1
      return segments + [0] * (max_seq_length - len(tokens))

def get_ids(tokens, tokenizer, max_seq_length):
    if len(tokens)>max_seq_length:
      tokens = tokens[:max_seq_length]
      token_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
      return token_ids
    else:
      token_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
      input_ids = token_ids + [0] * (max_seq_length-len(token_ids))
      return input_ids

tokenizer = createTokenizer()
max_seq_length = 2  #This number will determine the number of tokens

def prep(s, get = 'id'):
    stokens = tokenizer.tokenize(s)
    stokens = ["[CLS]"] + stokens + ["[SEP]"]
    if get == 'id':
        input_ids = get_ids(stokens, tokenizer, max_seq_length)
        return input_ids
    elif get == 'mask':
        input_masks = get_masks(stokens, max_seq_length)
        return input_masks
    else:
        input_segments = get_segments(stokens, max_seq_length)
        return input_segments

#train과 test 데이터 로드
import pandas as pd
import pickle
train_set = pd.read_csv("../goemotion/train_set.csv")
test_set = pd.read_csv("../goemotion/test_set.csv")

train_X = [prep(sentence) for sentence in train_set["text"]]
#with open("train"+str(max_seq_length)+".pickle", 'rb') as f:
#    train_X = pickle.load(f)
train_Y = list(map(int, train_set["emotion"].tolist()))
test_X = [prep(sentence) for sentence in test_set["text"]]
#with open("test"+str(max_seq_length)+".pickle", 'rb') as f:
#    test_X = pickle.load(f)
test_Y = list(map(int, test_set["emotion"].tolist()))

with open("train"+str(max_seq_length)+".pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(train_X, f)
with open("test"+str(max_seq_length)+".pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(test_X, f)

print("data preprocess finished")

#albert 모델 호출
import os
import bert
import tensorflow as tf

"""
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
"""
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")[0], True)
'''with tf.device("CPU"):
    train_X = tf.identity(train_X)
    train_Y = tf.identity(train_Y)
    test_X = tf.identity(test_X)
    test_Y = tf.identity(test_Y)'''


#model calling No.1
model_name = "albert_base_v2"
#model_dir = bert.fetch_google_albert_model(model_name, ".models")
model_ckpt = os.path.join("../albert_base", "model.ckpt-best")
model_params = bert.albert_params("../albert_base/")

albert_layer = bert.BertModelLayer.from_params(model_params, name="albert")
model_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype="int32", name="input_ids"),
    albert_layer,
    #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(112, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(27, activation=tf.nn.softmax),#0~27
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model_layer.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_length))
bert.load_albert_weights(albert_layer, model_ckpt)

#
model_layer.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001), metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])

print(model_layer.summary())

#훈련 시작
checkpointName = os.path.join("../albert_base/models/", "albert_faq.ckpt")

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpointName,
                                                save_weights_only=True,
                                                verbose=1)
history = model_layer.fit(
            test_X,
            test_Y,
            epochs=300,
            validation_data=(train_X, train_Y),
            verbose=1,
            callbacks=[cp_callback],
            batch_size=2)
```

above is my code and

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.23.04    Driver Version: 455.23.04    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3090    On   | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 33%   53C    P2   111W / 350W |   1016MiB / 24265MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

this is nvidia-smi

I use tensorflow-gpu 2.2 and cuda toolkit 10.1 and cudnn 7.6

My computer is 3900X 128GB(RAM) RTX3090 500GB(SSD)

and if run above code error message is below.

```
File "/home/sentiment/anaconda3/envs/mybert/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 6606, in raise_from_not_ok_status
six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 in order to run Identity: GPU sync failed [Op:Identity]
```

I want to train albert finetuning.
if i use tensorflow for cpu, it work fine, but 1 epoch per 6 hour for training.
so I hope to use gpu

I really hard to find out solution for fixing but failed.

is there anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: the line `with tf.device("CPU"):` looks strange. Why do you use CPU when training on GPU ?

Comment: @Andrey oh that's mistake to write on. someone said that that code work, but it didn't.